MySQL 8, Add unique column without locking
Note: I did look up other answers, but they all seem to be for MySQL 5.x. MySQL 8 has made huge strides in ease of altering tables so I am looking for mySQL 8 specific answers.
I'm using MySQL 8.0.36
I need to add a new column to a large table that must be unique (null OK) and that has an index on that column.
I thought, yeah!, MySQL 8 now has ALGORITHM=INSTANT for adding columns. However, ALGORITHM=INSTANT isn't accepted for making the column unique or adding an index. So I did:
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN new_col CHAR(20), ALGORITHM=INSTANT;

As promised, it was instant. 0.97 seconds.
Then:
CREATE INDEX xx ON mytable(new_col) ALGORITHM=INPLACE LOCK=NONE;

That took 7 minutes, but didn't lock the database. So OK.
However, lock=None isn't accepted for unique constraint. It gives me a syntax error. I'd have to do:
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD UNIQUE (new_col), ALGORITHM=INPLACE;

I'm afraid to do that. I can't lock my production table for 7 minutes or however long it's going to take.
Am I missing something? MySQL 8 adding this powerful instant algorithm for adding columns, but I still can't do what I need.
My work-around, which I've used in the past, was to create a new table with the new column and join in my queries. That gets messy!

What data is going into this column or how is it getting populated?

Int and varchar. The new column is varchar(). It gets populated with the usual insert into mytable ...

Oh, in case it matters, the table was originally created on MySQL 5.7 and then upgraded to 8.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html says:

When you create a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY index, MySQL must do some extra work. For UNIQUE indexes, MySQL checks that the table contains no duplicate values for the key. For a PRIMARY KEY index, MySQL also checks that none of the PRIMARY KEY columns contains a NULL.

I infer that this means that while it's checking that the table contains no duplicate values for the key, it must block DML changes, because that would create a race condition.
You could use one of the community online schema change tools like pt-online-schema-change or gh-ost to avoid the blocking. But this creates another risk, i.e. what happens if there are duplicates in the column as you're creating a unique index? Should the OSC fail immediately, or should it skip the row (this happens in pt-osc for example), or should it null out the duplicate value, or some other behavior?

Thanks! I figured there wasn't some magic no lock solution, but thought I'd ask first. MySQL 8 did add a lot of new features.

And jokes on me because it's not accepting algorithm=instant for the drop column statement (that I just added using instant)  so now I'll just have this extra column in my table.

That is a situation you could fix using one of the OSC tools. If you have a production system that is sensitive to downtime, I recommend learning one of these tools.
